# List of questions to cleanup

Tags: discussion

Stuff we should close:

- [Is MP3 good for cats?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/46425/4057)
- [Setting on Zoom H5](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/46427/4057)
- [How can I send an audio re-recordered by whatsapp without distortion](https://sound.stackexchange.com/q/46447/4057)

Comment: I'm new here, but it may be best to sum up *why* these need to be removed? The 1st link is dead btw